# Removing all directories keeping files untouched (Windows cmd)

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to write a .bat file that deletes all directories in a specified directory, but not files. How could I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to remove only empty directories? Or do you want to move all directory contents to the root directory and remove the subdirectories? - You should look into the syntax to [`rd`](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)

Comment: Basically I have a directory with several archives and folders with unpacked archives. What I need to do is to delete the folders and re-unpack the archives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
for /f %%d in ('dir /b /ad') do rmdir %%d
```

to delete all empty directories in the current working directory.

The `/b` switch gives just the summary, so just one entry per line.

The `/ad` switch gives only directories.

`rd` (or `rmdir`) deletes only empty directories by default.

**Edit:**

As deadlyDev pointed out, you could add `/S /Q` to `RD` to remove non-empty directories, resulting in

```
for /f %%d in ('dir /b /ad') do rmdir /s /q %%d
```

Comment: You can add /S /Q to to rd (ie. rd /S /Q "%x") to remove non-empty directories.

Comment: Alexander, I've fixed the scripts in your answer a little bit. But the original idea of script was absolutely correct, thank you very much!  deadlyDev, thank you too!